# How to send tax and shipping to paypal sandbox?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

Here is my code:
This code allows me to add rate and quantity to paypal but tax and shipping seems to be impossible for me to be added.

So, please help me to counter this issue.
Tell me, if there is some library for this in codeigniter or I have to modify this code?

```
public function do_purchase()
            {



$config['business'] = 'stars_1336125903_biz@a1professionals.com'; //Your PayPal account
                    $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
                    $config['return']               = base_url().'front/payment/notify_payment';
                    $config['cancel_return']        = base_url().'front/payment/cancel_payment';
                    $config['notify_url']           = base_url().'front/payment/notify_payment';
                    $config['production']           = FALSE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox

                    $config["shipping"] = 10;
                    $config["shipping2"] = 10;
                    $config["handling"] = 10;
                    $config["tax1"] = 10;
                    $config["invoice"]              = $this->inv; //The invoice id


                                    $config["first_name"] = $this->input->post('firstname');
                                    $config["last_name"] = $this->input->post('lastname');
                                    $config["address1"] = $this->input->post('address1');
                                    $config["address2"] = $this->input->post('address2');
                                    $config["country"] = $this->input->post('country');
                                    $config["state"] = $this->input->post('state');
                                    $config["city"] = $this->input->post('city');
                                    $config["zip"] = $this->input->post('postalcode');
                                    $config["email"] = 'testerone@a1professionals.com';
                                    //To save shipping add

                                    $this->load->library('paypal',$config);
                                    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items)
                                        {
                                            #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);
                                            $this->paypal->add($items['name'],$items['price'],$items['qty'],$items['id']); //First item
                                        }
                                    $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
            }
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem with the tax. I am using http://tutsnare.com/integrate-paypal-using-ci-merchant-in-codeigniter/